# Bootstrap tooltip/popover not showing properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip, angular

I'm using Angular 2 to build my web application. When I try to put a tooltip or popover on an image or button, I get the [default-looking tooltip](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/qH0bi9OT3g2w1WakseL_ziOBG2bGE-R0SjQZqsLNf_4) instead of the bootstrap one.

I've tried the [basic W3Schools examples](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover&stacked=h) and did everything as shown, yet it doesn't work.

I believe my problem lies with the correct imports of the bootstrap.js or jQuery, but other bootstrap items like buttons etc. do work properly.

(I use nodejs to install the necessary files/dependencies -> `npm install` `npm install bootstrap` `npm install jquery`)

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/"><!--Without this tag, the browser may not be be able to load resources (images, css, scripts) when "deep linking" into the app. Bad things could happen when someone pastes an application link into the browser's address bar or clicks such a link in an email link. -->
    <title>Factory</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />-->

    <!-- stackoverflow suggested settings -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/boot')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<my-app></my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**page-with-tooltip(.ts)**

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import ... from ...;
import ... from ...;
...

@Component({
    template: `

<div *ngIf="hall" class="container">
    <h2>Detail van hal <small>{{hall.name}}</small></h2>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hall-box-single">
            <div class="hall-box"
                [style.width]="hall.areaWidth*4"
                [style.height]="hall.areaHeight*4">
                <div class="image-container">
                <div *ngFor="#item of hall.items">
                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Popover title">
                    <img [src]="item.image"
                         [style.left]="item.posX"
                         [style.top]="item.posY"/>
                     </a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>
`})

export class HallDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    constructor(...) {
        ...
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        ...
        (<any>$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')).tooltip();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
}
```

**!Edit!**

Added suggestions from users as well as an extract of the [running webpage source](http://pastebin.com/rZNEetFD).

Comment: I think you are missing a `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` in your `<script>...</script>`. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#callout-tooltip-opt-in for more info.

Comment: @adilapapaya I tried that before, but neither tooltip nor popover work properly. In the second code extract you can see at the bottom `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`

Comment: better if you use components like [ng-tooltip](https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-tooltip) or [ng-popover](https://github.com/pleerock/ng2-popover) without using jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `script` tag you wrote in your template is getting ignored, run your JS code from inside the component instead, I suggest you to run it in the `ngOnInit()` method since you are implementing the `OnInit` interface.

This should work:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `

        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>

    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
}
```

using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

So specific to your project:

You have three options to fix it:
One is to set a nasty timeout so it initiates the tooltips until you get a response back from the server and they have actually rendered.
The second is to find some method like the ones we try that gets executed everytime the dom changes, not just the first time.
The third and best but a bit more complicated is by implementing a method that gets executed before the page starts rendering, and if you return a promise in that method, the page will wait for the Promise to get done before rendering, so you can return a promise and resolve the promise until you get the answer from the service, that way the dom will be ready the first time the controller loads
I believe the last method is called CanActivate or something like that.

Comment: How can I run JS code from inside a component? Never done or seen it before.

Comment: Added the example into the answer post.

Comment: [not working](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/v0db4OcrLsm4E9kBtZhIGSOBG2bGE-R0SjQZqsLNf_4)

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? are you getting any errors in the console? (Hit F12 > Console, tab to see it)

Comment: I just tried it and it works, change popover for tooltip in both the js code and the html and get rid of all the lib links overriding each other, you are overriding 3.3.6 with 3.3.5:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">` , same thing with jquery and "tooltip.js" is already part of bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Still doesn't work, I do exactly the same as in plunker and bs3 examples, but it doesn't work :s

Comment: You are repeating the jquery, and you have the code that initializes the tooltip commented out, that is not how you are testing it right?

Comment: I just saw the image of the error you are getting, that's what you mean by not working? that error is just because bootstrap is not written on typescript so it doesn't recognize the tooltip function, there's a couple of ways to address that but its a whole subject on its own, you can make that error go away by using this line instead: `(<any>$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')).tooltip();` but the tooltip should still work even if you get that error, are you not seing the tooltip yet?

Comment: I see [the tooltip](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-7jqsBuXlJIs/VpIxA5f7h5I/AAAAAAAACCw/ZpYvFXcnpZE/s2048-Ic42/%25255BUNSET%25255D.png) but not in bootstrap format. I used your scripts and css, yet no result, all the other bootstrap components are displayed in the right way except for tooltips and popovers :s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100281/discussion-between-edward-and-langley).

Comment: I updated the question and added the source of the running webpage, looks like the bottom `<script>$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();</script>` is not being put into the webpage, but maybe the ngOnInit fixes that on its own, not sure.

Comment: That's what I said in my answer, the script tag and all the code you wrote in the template is going to be ignored, that's why you are writing it in the controller itself.

Comment: So where should I best put these scripts? If it's html it has to be put into the `template: ` `` of a component right? But imports happen in the `<head></head>` so the only place where I can put them now is in my index.html, which doesn't work. -- I'm new to all this angular2 mumbo jumbo so my apologies for the lack of knowledge on controllers etc.

Comment: You just don't do it in a script tag , you do it in the controller, just the way you are doing it after the fix, I copied and reproduced your error, just change the `ngOnInit` method for `ngAfterViewInit` instead. Once there's more documentation about the Renderer you'll figure out more and even better ways to do it, but for now that will fix it.

Comment: I added `implements AfterViewInit` to my class and the script-code from the ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit(), but it still shows me the same thing.

Comment: This method works for me. I was hoping to find a solution that used perhaps @ViewChild() and .nativeElement to be able to call .popover() on that to avoid jQuery entirely, but that doesn't seem to be possible. Can anyone confirm? I'm worried that jQuery might not play nice with Angular... maybe won't work properly with elements inside of an *ngIf block or something like that...